# Insert specific ID with hibernate on postgresql database

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

Java hibernate and Postgresql

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE players
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  ....
)
```

HBM:

```
<class name="Player" table="players">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
...
```

I want to be able to insert a specific ID in some cases as I'm importing data from another data source and need to maintain ID consistency.

When inserting with hibernate even when I set the ID of the object it still inserts without using the ID that I've specified.

Are there settings that I can change to support specifying the ID on insert?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I did want to alert you to a problem I've seen people report a few times -- if you insert rows with explicit values rather than letting them default from the sequence associated with the serial column, the sequence does not know about those values, and you can get duplicate key errors if you don't have a strategy for avoiding that.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I realize OP is primarily and specifically asking about Hibernate, which I'll admit, I have no experience with. I just felt the need to discuss why this doesn't seem advisable to me with ANY Object Relational Model.

I'm not sure that using an ORM to directly import data is such a good idea.  Tf you are importing data and the  IDs of the data imported are in the range of the yet-to-be-generated, you should eventually get duplicates (or primary key issues if set up that way).  Postgresql creates separate `sequence` objects to maintain sequences which should be unaffected by the tables that use them.  Any solution using an ORM should also address that issue as well.   Looks like that can be manipulated through Postgresql evaluation of `setval` (see  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html)

If you still need to use an ORM for this, I'd be tempted to create some data "landing" tables, generate classes for them with your ORM tools, and then write some SQL function that patches your live tables with the data you just uploaded.  There may be another, better way, but I'd like to see it.

Comment: How is this an insult?  I just thought this was a bad idea.  I've had to implement plenty of bad ideas.

Comment: Well, maybe "bad idea" is too strong... My point was it likely needs something in addition.

Comment: And perhaps it does, perhaps doing it via sql statements would be more effective.